# SQL Query - Return field where data was found

Tags: sql-server

I have a phone number search query in SQL and I would like to know how I can have a column displaying in what field data was found. There's any way to do that?
This is my query:

```
Select DISTINCT ST.SCHOOLID, 
ST.STUDENT_NUMBER,
ST.LASTFIRST, 
ST.GRADE_LEVEL
FROM PS.STUDENTS ST
LEFT OUTER JOIN PS.U_GUARDIANS GA
ON ST.DCID = GA.STUDENTSDCID
LEFT OUTER JOIN PS.U_DEMO DE
ON ST.DCID = DE.STUDENTSDCID
LEFT OUTER JOIN PS.U_EMERGENCY EME
ON ST.DCID = EME.STUDENTSDCID
LEFT OUTER JOIN PS.U_STUDENT_HISTORY PREV
ON ST.DCID = EME.STUDENTSDCID
WHERE ST.Home_Phone LIKE '%param1%'
OR DE.STUDENT_CELL LIKE '%param1%'
OR GA.G1_PHONE1 LIKE '%param1%'
OR GA.G1_PHONE2 LIKE '%param1%'
OR GA.G1_WORK_PHONE LIKE '%param1%'
OR GA.G2_PHONE1 LIKE '%param1%'
OR GA.G2_PHONE2 LIKE '%param1%'
OR GA.G2_WORK_PHONE LIKE '%param1%'
OR GA.G3_PHONE1 LIKE '%param1%'
OR GA.G3_PHONE2 LIKE '%param1%'
OR GA.G3_WORK_PHONE LIKE '%param1%'
OR GA.G4_PHONE1 LIKE '%param1%'
OR GA.G4_PHONE2 LIKE '%param1%'
OR GA.G4_WORK_PHONE LIKE '%param1%'
OR EME.EC1_Phone1 LIKE '%param1%'
OR EME.EC1_Phone2 LIKE '%param1%'
OR EME.EC2_Phone1 LIKE '%param1%'
OR EME.EC2_Phone2 LIKE '%param1%'
OR EME.EC3_Phone1 LIKE '%param1%'
OR EME.EC3_Phone2 LIKE '%param1%'
OR PREV.Prev_School_Phone LIKE '%param1%'
OR PREV.Prev_School_Fax LIKE '%param1%'
OR ST.Doctor_Phone LIKE '%param1%' 
order by ST.lastfirst
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use a `CROSS APPLY`:

```
Select DISTINCT 
    ST.SCHOOLID, 
    ST.STUDENT_NUMBER,
    ST.LASTFIRST, 
    ST.GRADE_LEVEL,
    C.Col -- Column name
FROM PS.STUDENTS ST
LEFT OUTER JOIN PS.U_GUARDIANS GA
    ON ST.DCID = GA.STUDENTSDCID
LEFT OUTER JOIN PS.U_DEMO DE
    ON ST.DCID = DE.STUDENTSDCID
LEFT OUTER JOIN PS.U_EMERGENCY EME
    ON ST.DCID = EME.STUDENTSDCID
LEFT OUTER JOIN PS.U_STUDENT_HISTORY PREV
    ON ST.DCID = EME.STUDENTSDCID
CROSS APPLY
(
    VALUES
    ('ST.Home_Phone', ST.Home_Phone),
    ('DE.STUDENT_CELL', DE.STUDENT_CELL),
    ('GA.G1_PHONE1', GA.G1_PHONE1),
    ('GA.G1_PHONE2', GA.G1_PHONE2),
    ('GA.G1_WORK_PHONE', GA.G1_WORK_PHONE),
    ('GA.G2_PHONE1', GA.G2_PHONE1),
    ('GA.G2_PHONE2', GA.G2_PHONE2),
    ('GA.G2_WORK_PHONE', GA.G2_WORK_PHONE),
    ('GA.G3_PHONE1', GA.G3_PHONE1),
    ('GA.G3_PHONE2', GA.G3_PHONE2),
    ('GA.G3_WORK_PHONE', GA.G3_WORK_PHONE),
    ('GA.G4_PHONE1', GA.G4_PHONE1),
    ('GA.G4_PHONE2', GA.G4_PHONE2),
    ('GA.G4_WORK_PHONE', GA.G4_WORK_PHONE),
    ('EME.EC1_Phone1', EME.EC1_Phone1),
    ('EME.EC1_Phone2', EME.EC1_Phone2),
    ('EME.EC2_Phone1', EME.EC2_Phone1),
    ('EME.EC2_Phone2', EME.EC2_Phone2),
    ('EME.EC3_Phone1', EME.EC3_Phone1),
    ('EME.EC3_Phone2', EME.EC3_Phone2),
    ('PREV.Prev_School_Phone', PREV.Prev_School_Phone),
    ('PREV.Prev_School_Fax', PREV.Prev_School_Fax),
    ('ST.Doctor_Phone', ST.Doctor_Phone)
) AS C(Col, Val)
WHERE C.Val LIKE '%param1%'
ORDER BY ST.lastfirst;
```

If the column types are not the same type (e.g. one is an integer), this may throw an error, in which case you'll need to convert the columns to the same type in the cross apply.

This method will also duplicate the rows for each column that matches (e.g. if it matches on columns A and B, you'll get one row with val1, val2, val3, val4, A and one row with val1, val2, val3, val4, B). This could be fixed with a slight adjustment to how the cross apply works if that is an issue.

**EDIT:**

As an example with sample data, running this will show you what the query should do:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE 
(
    SchoolID INT NOT NULL, Student_Number INT NOT NULL, LastFirst INT NOT NULL, Grade_Level INT NOT NULL,
    Home_Phone VARCHAR(255), Student_Cell VARCHAR(255), Phone1 VARCHAR(255), Phone2 VARCHAR(255), Phone3 VARCHAR(255),
    Phone4 VARCHAR(255), RandomColumnName VARCHAR(255), ABCDEFGHIJKL VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT @T (SchoolID, Student_Number, LastFirst, Grade_Level, Home_Phone, Student_Cell, Phone1, Phone2, Phone3, Phone4, RandomColumnName, ABCDEFGHIJKL) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, 1, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'sdgfagagparam1sdasf', NULL, NULL),
(1, 1, 1, 2, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'asdfparam1sadf', NULL, NULL, NULL),
(1, 1, 1, 3, NULL, NULL, 'param1asdf', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(1, 1, 2, 1, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'adfparam1', NULL),
(1, 1, 2, 2, NULL, 'qqqparam1', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(1, 2, 1, 2, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'param1', NULL, NULL, 'param1'),
(2, 1, 1, 2, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

SELECT DISTINCT 
    T.SchoolID, 
    T.Student_Number, 
    T.LastFirst, 
    T.Grade_Level, 
    C.Col
FROM @T AS T
CROSS APPLY
(
    VALUES
    ('Home_Phone', Home_Phone),
    ('Student_Cell', Student_Cell),
    ('Phone1', Phone1),
    ('Phone2', Phone2),
    ('Phone3', Phone3),
    ('Phone4', Phone4),
    ('RandomColumnName', RandomColumnName),
    ('ABCDEFGHIJKL', ABCDEFGHIJKL)
) AS C(Col, Val)
WHERE C.Val LIKE '%param1%';
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I tried using the code above and I was wondering what I should enter on C.Col -- Column name ? Is that just the name I want to use on that column since this is not a field on the database is just a column I want to add to return the field name. Sorry I am still on very basics of SQL. Anyways I tried using the code above and just replaced C.Col -- Column name to C.Field and added a header for that column but when I try to search does not return anything. I also tried removing distinct from the query but also did not return anything.

Comment: Sorry, when you run the above code without changing anything, I expected it to just work. The comment there was just a comment to show you what you should expect to see when you run it. When you run the above query without changing anything, do you still get no results?

Comment: I've edited in a plain example with sample data to show what your query should be displaying when you run it.